# Работа с глобальными переменными

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в своем проектике организовать работу с глобальными изменяемыми переменными, которые доступны в любом месте? Если имеет значение, примерная иерархия проекта:

```
project/
---- models/
---- ---- first.py
---- ---- second.py
---- run.py
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что это хорошая идея?

Comment: Скорее у меня нет выбора, ведь у меня есть сокет подключение, к которому может обратиться любая функция, а также несколько других текстовых переменных, которые изменяются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно создать модуль с переменными и подключать его из других модулей

Comment: так и сделал, спасибо